# How to overide default Entity Framework constructor

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have this class which was defined in Entify Framework (Database first) which contains the following columns

```
ID (guid)
Name (string)
Active (bool)
Some Other stuff...
```

The name column should actually be the result of some "calculation" which is something like "CurrentYear + ParentName"

I could easily get that information right before saving, but I what I would like is to get that information before.

I know that whatever information I put into the default value in the edmx will come off right and I checked in the generated file. I see a normal constructor which does it.

So my question is actually rather simple. How can I "override" this constructor. If I can't, is there any way to add some calculation in the default value of an entity ?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem will be when you update your edmx file from the database. Every time you do that your changes will be reverted.

Comment: You can add a constructor with parameters to a partial file.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom : I know. That's my main problem. Gert, it will sound weird, but I don't I can, in this situation, have a consructor with parameter.

Comment: There already is a constructor with a parameter? Where does it come from? EF requires parameterless constructors. Please add more relevant detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// your custom class
public partial class MyEntityClass
{
   public string CustomName => CurrentYear.ToString() + ParentName;
}

// EF Generated class
public partial class MyEntityClass
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int CurrentYear { get; set; }
   public string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea for simple case, but suppose I need to get the information from a linked object for exemple ?

Comment: Tbh haven't tried something like that, if i will found out some solution i will post ^^

Comment: Actually, this would mean though that the CustomName would not be found within the database right ? This can'T do it then